# C++; Iterate over vector of structs and access struct members

Tags: c++, loops, vector, struct, iterator

I have a struct:

```
struct fsobject {
std::string fqname; //Fully Qualified Name of File incl extension
std::string type;   //Type of Object, Either Directory or File
std::string data;   //contents of file. Directories have no data.
};
```

And a vector of type fsobject:

```
std::vector<fsobject> driveA;//Drive A
```

I am trying to iterate over the vector and access struct members for each vector element. This is the loop I have created:

```
for (auto vectorit = driveA.begin(); vectorit != driveA.end(); ++vectorit)
{
    cout << vectorit.fqname <<endl;
}
```

Which results in the error:

main.cpp|50|error: ‘class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >’ has no member named ‘fqname’|

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to accomplish accessing members of each vector element. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the full source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>

struct fsobject {
std::string fqname; //Fully Qualified Name of File incl extension
std::string type;   //Type of Object, Either Directory or File
std::string data;   //contents of file. Directories have no data.
};


using namespace std;

bool compare(const fsobject& first, const fsobject& second)
{
  if (first.fqname < second.fqname)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<fsobject> driveA;//Drive A
    std::vector<fsobject> driveB;//Drive B
    std::vector<fsobject> driveC;//Drive C

    driveA.push_back({"/home/zory/","dir",""});
    driveA.push_back({"/home/dory/","dir",""});
    driveA.push_back({"/home/","dir",""});
    driveA.push_back({"/home/anakin/","dir",""});
    driveA.push_back({"/home/luke/","dir",""});
    driveA.push_back({"/home/luke/","dir",""});
    driveA.push_back({"/home/luke/QuaterlyReports.pdf","file","bankruptcy is coming"});

    sort(driveA.begin(),driveA.end(),compare);
    /*cout << driveA.back().fqname << endl;
    driveA.pop_back();
    cout << driveA.back().fqname << endl;*/



    for (auto vectorit = driveA.begin(); vectorit != driveA.end(); ++vectorit)
    {
        cout << vectorit.fqname <<endl;
    }


    cout << "Done...";

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you wanted `vectorit->fqname`.

Comment: `vectorit` is an `std::vector<fsobject>::iterator`. Iterators are like pointers, you use them withs `->`,

Comment: @JamesRoot I  tried that. It will compile and run but does not produce any output. I know that the struct members are populated. I can access the members with driveA.back().fqname, pop, and repeat outside of the iteration to demonstrate this knowledge.

Comment: @n.m. please see above.

Comment: @FantasticSponge If you tried that, and it fixed the error, why would you intentionally break it again?

Comment: @FantasticSponge, works fine at http://ideone.com/BmO6Bp and on my desktop too.

Comment: @JamesRoot, it didn't fix it, I don't want to pop my vector elements, just iterate over them.

Comment: `->` is right. `.` is wrong. If you tried `->` and your program doesn't work, something else is wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

[C++ STL Vector Iterator accessing members of an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322128/c-stl-vector-iterator-accessing-members-of-an-object)

```
    cout << (*vectorit).fqname;
```

Results in the expected output. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: This is the same as `vectorit->fqname`. The `->` operator is here as shorthand for the above syntax.

Comment: You're correct. Silly mistake on my part.